# Sequelize many-to-many formatter

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following relation:

```
var Order = sequelize.define('order', {
  id : {
    type          : Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey    : true,
    autoIncrement : true
  },
  amount       : { type : Sequelize.DOUBLE },
  change       : { type : Sequelize.DOUBLE },
  status       : { type : Sequelize.ENUM('draft', 'placed', 'in_transit', 'fulfilled', 'rejected') },
  statusReason : { type : Sequelize.STRING },
  address      : { type : Sequelize.STRING },
  latitude     : { type : Sequelize.DOUBLE },
  longitude    : { type : Sequelize.DOUBLE }
})

var Beverage = sequelize.define('beverage', {
  id : {
    type          : Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey    : true,
    autoIncrement : true
  },
  name    : { type : Sequelize.STRING },
  picture : { type : Sequelize.STRING },
  price   : { type : Sequelize.DOUBLE },
  max     : { type : Sequelize.DOUBLE },
})

var OrderBeverage = sequelize.define('orderBeverage', {
  id : {
    type          : Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey    : true,
    autoIncrement : true
  },
  orderId    : { type : Sequelize.INTEGER },
  beverageId : { type : Sequelize.INTEGER },
  amount     : { type : Sequelize.INTEGER }
})

Order.hasMany(OrderBeverage, { as : 'beverages' })
OrderBeverage.belongsTo(Beverage)
OrderBeverage.belongsTo(Order)
```

So, if I make a simple query including the relation, I have the following source and result:

```
let orders = yield Order.findAll({
  include : [{
    model      : Order.Beverage,
    as         : 'beverages',
    attributes : ['createdAt'],
    include    : [ Beverage ]
  }]
})
```

and the resulting json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "amount": 0,
    "change": 0,
    "status": "placed",
    "statusReason": "wrong address given",
    "address": "street x, michigan",
    "latitude": 0,
    "longitude": 0,
    "createdAt": "2016-01-12T22:39:32.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-01-13T21:05:06.000Z",
    "beverages": [
      {
        "createdAt": "2016-01-12T23:10:48.000Z",
        "beverage": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Vodka",
          "picture": "somepic",
          "price": 30,
          "max": 5,
          "createdAt": "2016-01-12T22:26:10.000Z",
          "updatedAt": "2016-01-12T22:26:10.000Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to make the attribute `beverages` be the array of the beverage's content, and not be an array of `{ createdAt, beverage }` that beverage's content is inside `beverage` key.

The final result would look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "amount": 0,
    "change": 0,
    "status": "placed",
    "statusReason": "wrong address given",
    "address": "street x, michigan",
    "latitude": 0,
    "longitude": 0,
    "createdAt": "2016-01-12T22:39:32.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-01-13T21:05:06.000Z",
    "beverages": [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Vodka",
          "picture": "somepic",
          "price": 30,
          "max": 5,
          "createdAt": "2016-01-12T22:26:10.000Z",
          "updatedAt": "2016-01-12T22:26:10.000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've searched through the documentation and could not find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out how to accomplish that. It's **not intuitive** by any means.

Instead of using a `hasMany` relation with `OrderBeverage`:

```
Order.hasMany(OrderBeverage, { as : 'beverages' })
```

we have to use `belongsToMany` relation with `Beverage` through `OrderBeverage`:

```
Order.belongsToMany(Beverage, { through : 'orderBeverage' })
```

With that, we simply modify the query to be like:

```
let orders = yield Order.findAll({
  include : [{
    model : Beverage
  }]
})
```

I think this doesn't makes much sense, since **beverage** belongs to many **orderBeverage**, and not **order** belongs to many **beverage** through **orderBeverage**.

In a sense, **beverage** belongs to many **order** through **orderBeverage**.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the idea and concept...